# Tensorflow - add 2x2 matrix to 4x4 fractal at starting index

Tags: python, tensorflow

Consider a n x n tensor, such as:

```
board = tf.zeros([9,9], dtype=tf.int32)
```

How do I add another tensor (matrix) to it? If this isn't possible, I want to know how to update the value of the (original) tensor (beginning at location (x, y)) with the values in the smaller to_add tensor. Thanks.

```
to_add = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype=tf.int32)
```

For example, how do I add the following matrices, starting at (1,0)

```
0 0 0       1 0        0 1 0 
0 0 0   +   1 0    =   0 1 0 
0 0 0                  0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

board = tf.zeros([9,9], dtype=tf.int32)
to_add = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype=tf.int32)
start = (2, 3)

def add_t_to_t(t_large, t_small, start):
    i, j = start
    m, n = t_small.shape
    large = t_large.numpy()
    large[i:i + m, j:j + n] += t_small.numpy()
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(large)

board = add_t_to_t(board, to_add, start)
print(board)
```

prints

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 7 8 9 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]], shape=(9, 9), dtype=int32)
```

Wouldn't know how to do this with pure tensorflow, but I am sure there is a (more cumbersome) way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

`Add` follows NumPy broadcasting rules, so you need to add tensors that have the same shape. What you could use is `tf.pad()` function to add padding to your `to_add` and make it the same shape as `board`

Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
board = tf.zeros([9,9], dtype=tf.int32)
to_add = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype=tf.int32)

padding = tf.constant([[0,6],[1,5]], dtype=tf.int32)
padded = tf.pad(to_add, padding)
print('Pad:')
print(padded)

print('New Board:')
new_board = tf.add(board, padded)
print(new_board)
```

Output:

```
Pad:
tf.Tensor(
[[0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]], shape=(9, 9), dtype=int32)
New Board:
tf.Tensor(
[[0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]], shape=(9, 9), dtype=int32)
```